# When did owner disappear from the net_device struct? 'struct net_device' has no member named 'owner'

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Isn't owner supposed to be part of the `net_device` structure?  I saw threads indicating the macro `SET_MODULE_OWNER` (which assigned the member) was/is/potentially being deprecated, but I thought I understood that the member would remain in the structure. Did it disappear at some version of the kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern kernel git repository doesn't have this change. You can use [full kernel history repository](https://landley.net/kdocs/local/linux-fullhist.tar.bz2) to find out the change:

```
$ git log -S'struct module *owner;' -- include/linux/netdevice.h
```

shows this commit:

```
Author: David S. Miller <davem@nuts.ninka.net>
Date:   Mon May 19 04:30:48 2003 -0700

    [NET]: Fix netdevice unregister races.
```

Wow, it was 13 years ago, pretty old stuff. Here is the commit itself: [link](http://git.meleeweb.net/linux.git/commit/?id=ff936f4e8148e75b20595eda5de6d3a4bb55b631). And the change you are looking for:

```c
-       /* open/release and usage marking */
-       struct module *owner;
```

So it looks like (from the patch) that you can just forget about that `owner` stuff. To figure out the kernel version when this commit was done:

```
$ git tag --contains 558d700c48 | head -1
```

which shows `v2.6.0`. And previous tag is `v2.4.0`. So it was done between 2.4 and 2.6.

Actually, by googling the patch name, we can find out that it was added exactly in [2.5.70](https://lwn.net/Articles/33718/) version.

The same can be done to figure out where `SET_MODULE_OWNER` has gone. This patch removes it:

```
Author: Ralf Baechle <ralf@linux-mips.org>
Date:   Mon Sep 17 13:11:17 2007 -0700

    [NET]: Nuke SET_MODULE_OWNER macro.
```

And the whole patch can be seen [here](http://git.meleeweb.net/linux.git/commit/?id=10d024c1b2fd58af8362670d7d6e5ae52fc33353). Patch was merged in `v2.6.24`.